# react-native : How to define a javascript class

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am using react native. I need to define a class:

```
class myClass {
  email: string;
  name: string;
  constructor() {
      setUser(fbid: string, token: string): boolean {
```

I am trying to define it in its own file myClass.js and when I include it in my index.ios.js , I get this error:

```
Can't find variable: myClass
```

Can you please point me to any documentation on how to define non react classes and use them in react native ? Thank you for reading.

Comment: i'm not familiar with reactjs but if you're looking to create a class in JS this should help, particularly the `Custom objects` section : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript

Comment: [ReactJS](https://facebook.github.io/react/)  is a JavaScript library.    

[React Native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/) is a mobile framework, don't mistake them for the same thing.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to export classes you define.

example:

```
//myClass.js
export default class myClass {
  email: string;
  name: string;
  constructor() {
      //...
  }
}

//index.ios.js
import myClass from './path/to/myClass.js'
```

Note the "export default", so you can define **any** class including non-react classes in a React Native (or Javascript es6) project and export it, making it available for import and use by other classes.

See 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export

for more details.