# React Native Models

Tags: react-native

I want to create some models for my react native application. I have come from an Angular background, so there is a complication between ts and js for me.

How can I create a simple customer model in react native? How can I convert this ts code to js?

```
export interface Customer {
 id: numner;
 firstName: string;
 lastName: string;
}
```

Comment: Check this for more info, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35804841/react-native-how-to-define-a-javascript-class

Comment: I tried it. But is says, types can only be used in ts.

Comment: Do you want to create models because you want to access them in all your components?

Comment: I want classes to map with the backend responses. something like this in type script.

import { Photo } from "./photo";

export interface User {
  id: number;
  username: string;
  knownAs: string;
  age: number;
  gender: string;
  created: Date;
  lastActive: Date;
  photoUrl: string;
  city: string;
  country: {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    continent: {
      id: number;
      name: string;
    };
  };
  interests?: string;
  introduction?: string;
  lookingFor?: string;
  photos?: Photo[];
}

Comment: For what reason? If you are just using RN local state within your component to hold your backend data from your api then just create local objects within your component to map to the backend response. If you want to access this data throughout your application then consider using something like Redux and then you can access all this through the global store

Comment: I search for this too. This is MVC approach, like in Python's Django that I use on my backend. In perfect world I would have abstract object definition for both backend (django) and frontend (react native) to work with. Looks like its not here.

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
//myClass.js
export default class myClass {
  email: string;
  name: string;
  constructor() {
      //...
  }
}

//index.ios.js
import myClass from './path/to/myClass.js'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use TypeScript with react and react-native. For more info you can check [Static Type Checking documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/static-type-checking.html#typescript)

> TypeScript is a programming language developed by Microsoft. It is a
>   typed superset of JavaScript, and includes its own compiler. Being a
>   typed language, Typescript can catch errors and bugs at build time,
>   long before your app goes live. You can learn more about using
>   TypeScript with React here.
>
> To use TypeScript, you need to:
>
> - Add Typescript as a dependency to your project
> - Configure the TypeScript compiler options
> - Use the right file extensions
> - Add definitions for libraries you use
>
> Let’s go over these in detail.

There is a [detailed post](https://medium.com/@rintoj/react-native-with-typescript-40355a90a5d7) from [Rinto Jose](https://medium.com/@rintoj) that shows setup TypeScript for react-native.

```
npm install typescript tslint rimraf concurrently --save-dev
npm install @types/react @types/react-native @types/jest --save-dev

{
  "scripts": {
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "lint": "tslint src/**/*.ts"
    "clean": "rimraf artifacts",
    "build": "npm run clean && npm run tsc --"
  }
}
```